# Is there an English dialect that distinguishes between stressed /oʊ/ from its final unstressed form?

Tags: dialects, phonology

Is there any English dialect that distinguishes the stressed /oʊ/ as in *goat, throat, slope, broke, stroke*, etc. from the final, unstressed /oʊ/ as in *sparrow, arrow, tomorrow, yellow, window*, etc?

What does the unstressed /oʊ/ sound like in those dialects?

Comment: The unstressed is often reduced to a schwa sounding like “uh” in some southern US dialects.

Comment: You quite often see "Cockney sparra" written that way ("sparrow" meaning a person with sparrow-like characteristics). Not to be confused with various types of [goat split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Goat_split).

Comment: ["Sparra"](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/sparrow) is also a common spelling in Scots, but this probably relates to different phonetic processes, as the bird was *spearwa* in Old English.

Comment: What do you mean by "distinguish"? All vowels are different depending on position, including stress. That's the definition of what a [phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) is.

Comment: I believe this is the case in some East Anglian dialects like Norfolk: stressed is /ʊu/ and unstressed /ʌu/. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norfolk_dialect#Vowels

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive my lack of phonetic characters.

Scots has an ending rather like “-a”, “-uh” or “-er” in:

> Arrow = arra
>
> Tomorrow = ra morra {= the morrow}
>
> Sparrow = Sparra
>
> And Window = windae, pronounced winday with a short “ay” a bit like “-eh”
>
> [Stirling](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/%7Ekjt/general/scots.html#Pronunciation)
>
> And the site also includes a regional example of
>
> Glasgow = Glescae, ending rather like windae.

In the case of yellow, the Stirling university site offers no summary. I recommend that you listen to:

[Scotslanguage](https://www.scotslanguage.com/articles/node/id/373/type/referance)

Where in the well-known song “Yellow on the Broom” you will hear yellow = yella (or yeller).

Answer (score 1):

The UK Tyneside accent would pronounce goat and throat as /gəː<sup>ə</sup>t/ and /θrəː<sup>ə</sup>t/ and

arrow, etc., as /ˈara/, but this /əʊ/ to /a/ or /ə/ is common in the Midlands and North of England

Answer (score 1):

In Appalachian English, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English#:%7E:text=An%20%22%2Der%22%20sound%20is,(pronounced%20%22backer%22).) says

> An "-er" sound is often used for long "o" at the end of a word. For example, hollow— "a small, sheltered valley"— is pronounced /ˈhɑlər/, homophonous with holler. Other examples are "potato" (pronounced "tader"), "tomato" (pronounced "mader"), and "tobacco" (pronounced "backer").

So *winder, holler, tater*, etc. are pronounced with /ər/ and not /oʊ/.